# Is there a way to automtically identify the minimum supported browser versions for a script?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, cross-browser

I have a Webpack project that I currently test using Firefox 98. Since this is a small project, though, I can't spend hours testing every single feature on every browser (and although I can set up continuous integration to do that for me, I currently don't have the time to write all of the tests either).

[caniuse](https://caniuse.com/) links to [I want to use](https://iwanttouse.com), which allows you to see the percentages of users you can support with a given set of features. The problem is I've written quite a lot of code, and can't spend the time combing through all of the code I've written to check what browser features I've used either.

Is there a program or script, be it an npm package, website, Webpack plugin, or otherwise, that can automatically identify the minimum supported browser versions for every major browser? Given that the data for caniuse is public, I'd expect such a library to exist already, although I haven't been able to find anything from search on Google and npm.

Comment: I am think you are looking for https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist?

Comment: JavaScript itself shouldn't be a problem (you can "compile" it to almost any version), but the support of the DOM properties varies a lot.

Comment: @ikhvjs browserslist is used for setting what browser versions to support, meaning the code would need to be adjusted anyway. Although it can narrow down what versions we can use (by performing trial-and-error linter checks), this is still rather time consuming.

Comment: @Teemu Yeah, that's really what I'm looking for. It *should* be easy enough for an analysis script to detect the minimum required browser version for all features used in a script, such as the dialog element (73%) or `KeyboardEvent.code` (55%), and return the minimum version required for all those (e.g. for the two aforementioned, Chrome 48, Firefox 98, Safari 15.4).

Comment: Well, the question is actually off-topic for SO, but [CanIUse API](https://www.npmjs.com/package/caniuse-api) exists, you can create your own library.